# Has problems when pass a component as React setState value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'am confusing with this code snippet Because of I never wrote like this.

So! Does it has any problems? I'm not sure.

```
import React from "react"
import ChildComponent from "./ChildComponent"

class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
       component: null
    }

    componentDidMount() {
       this.setState({
          component: <ChildComponent />
       })
    }

    render() {
       return {this.state.component}
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example leads me to ask more questions. Is this supposed to be a minimal reproducible example? I ask because it seems like you should just render `ChildComponent`. What are you really trying to do? If the problem is this simple just try it.

Comment: this code was worked well in my project, i just want to know if it is elegant or recommend @DCTID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you don't want to store jsx/components in the state. Your state should contain minimal amount of data needed to represent your UI's state.

Coming back to your question, if you want to make your code work, store jsx in your state (not function/class reference). Also in your case, you don't need to render child component with a curly braces.

Working [demo of your code is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/small-rendering-issue-fix-wl3tw?file=/src/App.js)

**Code snippet**

```js
import React from "react"
import ChildComponent from "./ChildComponent"

export default class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
       component: null
    }

    componentDidMount() {
       this.setState({
          component: <ChildComponent /> //<----- like this
       })
    }

    render() {
       return this.state.component  //<----- like this
    }
}
```

Read [this](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/1248) for more info.